# Why is this ModuleNotFoundError error occuring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socketserver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SocketServer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'\
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mcve], reading the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section will also help you get more details that we need.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you provide reproducable sample code to replicate the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Error is because you did not install the package.

Install the package, before importing them

For Python command prompt,

```
pip install package_name
pip install httpserver
```

For Anaconda Navigator prompt,

```
conda install package_name
```

When Importing Socketsever, all in small letters (Package got renamed in python3)

```
import socketserver
```

Comment: what about simplehttpserver is it integrate with python 3

Comment: **pip install httpserver** this should do the trick

Comment: **import socketserver** in Python3 the package got renamed, all to lower case. socketserver not be installed it comes with the python distribution.